# check for empty fields android

Tags: android

code gets two user inputs from user and compares inputs to a database and prints out d corresponding data from the database.how do i add code to check for empty fields?

```
        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        try {
            boolean available=false;
            JSONArray Jarray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<Jarray.length();i++) {
                JSONObject Jasonobject = null;
                //text_1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
                Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                //get an output on the screen
                //String id = Jasonobject.getString("id");
                String name = Jasonobject.getString("name");
                String name1 = Jasonobject.getString("name1");
                String db_detail = "";

                if (et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(name) && et1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(name1)||et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(name1) && et1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    db_detail = Jasonobject.getString("detail");
                    text.setText(db_detail);
                    available = true;
                    break;

                }
            }
                if(!available)
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            this.progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `TextUtils.isEmpty(charactersequence)`

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(name)))
{

}
```

Docs :

```
public static boolean isEmpty (CharSequence str)
Added in API level 1

Returns true if the string is null or 0-length.
Parameters
str     the string to be examined
Returns

true if str is null or zero length
```

Also better to use `optString`

```
 Jasonobject.optString("name");
```

Comment: where should i put this code?I'm getting a cannot resolve symbol on d (name)

Comment: @PfilMintz check now i have shown for 1 do the same for others

Comment: @Raghunandan Sir Your logic perfect

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.isEmpty() method which checks whether the length of the String is 0.

You can also try on String.matches().

Using equalsIgnoreCase("") performs an actual string comparison. This method returns true if the argument is not null and the Strings are equal, ignoring case; false otherwise.

So you may check using isEmpty() or matches("") method to check empty values and then do the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

suppose your string you received is as below,

```
String nameString = jsonObj.getString("name");
```

you can check if its empty by using following check.

```
if(nameString.equals(""))
```